# Wildcard subdomain rewrites in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, wildcard

I'm trying to get nginx to rewrite

```
http://subdomain.example.com
```

to

```
http://example.com?username=subdomain
```

And not having any luck. Its important that the user sees the former URl in their browser but that nginx interprets it as the latter URL.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

nginx configuration:

```
server {
  server_name   ~^(?<subdomain>.+?)\.example\.com$;
  rewrite ^ /?username=$subdomain redirect;
}
```